# Interpreting binary as 2-bit pairs

Tags: vb.net, binary

I have code that converts text (from `Result.Text`) into binary in lines of 8:

```
Dim Resultconvert As String = String.Empty
For Each C As Char In Result.Text
    Dim s As String = System.Convert.ToString(AscW(C), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
    Debug.Print(s)
    Resultconvert &= s
Next
```

Output:

```
00110101
01000111
01010100
00111111
00101111
01111010
01100100
00111011
00101010
```

However, now I need it to interpret the string as 2-bit pairs,

Where `00=A, 01=T, 10=G, 11=C`

So the above would be interpreted and outputed to console as

```
ACTT
TATC
TTTA
ACCC
AGCC
TCGG
TGTA
ACGC
AGGG
```

So, essentially converting a real number between 0 and 1 into the quaternary system (AGCT)

If you have any ideas, please let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would need to split the string containing the binary number by a fixed length (2).  Unfortunately, there is no built in function to split a string by a fixed column-width like that.  It is, however, fairly easy to write your own method to do that, for instance:

```
Public Function SplitStringByLength(value As String, length As Integer) As String()
    Dim result((value.Length \ length) - 1) As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To result.Length - 1
        result(i) = value.Substring((i * length), length)
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Then, you can call that method and convert all the binary pairs, like this:

```
Dim Resultconvert As String = String.Empty
For Each C As Char In Result.Text
    Dim s As String = System.Convert.ToString(AscW(C), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
    Dim quaternary As String = ""
    For Each pair As String In SplitStringByLength(s, 2)
        Select Case pair
            Case "00": quaternary &= "A"
            Case "01": quaternary &= "T"
            Case "10": quaternary &= "G"
            Case "11": quaternary &= "C"
        End Select
    Next
    Debug.Print(s)
    Resultconvert &= s
Next
```

However, all of that converting the number to a string representation of a binary number and then parsing that string is rather inefficient and unnecessary.  The number is already stored in memory in binary, so with a little use of bit-wise operations you can do the same thing without ever converting to a string.  For instance, if you had a method like this:

```
Public Function ToQuaternary(value As Integer) As String
    Select Case value
        Case 0 : Return "A"  ' binary 00
        Case 1 : Return "T"  ' binary 01
        Case 2 : Return "G"  ' binary 10
        Case 3 : Return "C"  ' binary 11
        Case Else : Return Nothing
    End Select
End Function
```

Then you could just do something like this:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
For Each c As Char In Result.Text
    Dim charValue As Integer = AscW(c)
    builder.Append(ToQuaternary((charValue >> 6) And 3))
    builder.Append(ToQuaternary(charValue >> 4) And 3))
    builder.Append(ToQuaternary(charValue >> 2) And 3))
    builder.Append(ToQuaternary(charValue And 3))
    builder.AppendLine()
Next
Debug.Print(builder.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks Steven! They all look good. Will the second method work by outputting to console? For some reason I can't see anything being sent to the console, and I tried debug.print() no luck

Comment: I added a line to the end of that example which outputs the result with `Debug.Print`, like you were doing in your example.

Comment: Amazing! It completely works. You saved me a lot of time, thanks a lot Steven!!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, DNA. Cool. One of the things about real DNA is that the strands are *huge*, such that for real data, performance will definitely matter. With that in mind, I think your best bet is probably to build your own in a switch/state machine reading from System.IO.StringReader. Avoid the use of ReadLine() or Split(), because those will involve reading past the same data twice. I'm thinking something like this (**warning:** untested/typed directly into the reply box):

```
Function ConvertToIUPAC(Byval data As String) As String
    Dim result As New StringBuilder(data.Length/10 * 6) 'assumes 2-byte line endings

    Dim pair() as Character
    Dim rdr As New StringReader(data)
    Do
        For i As Integer = 0 To 3

            rdr.ReadBlock(pair, 0, 2)
            If pair[0] = "0"c  Then
                If pair[1] = "0"c Then
                    result.Append("A"c)
                Else
                    result.Append("T"c)
                End If
            Else
                If pair[1] = "0"c Then
                    result.Append("G"c)
                Else
                    result.Append("C"c)
                End If 
            End If
        Next
        result.Append(VbCrLf)
        rdr.ReadLine()

    Loop Until rdr.Peek() = -1 
    Return result.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Joel! Working with different number systems (especially DNA) is pretty fun. 

When you wrote `Dim pair() As Character` did you mean Characterrange or charactercasing ? This is what VS is asking me :)

Comment: Maybe it should just be "Char"